# how to cut a record?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

please help to avoid duplication of code.

I need to call get_count_authors_entries() of get_new_authors_entries()

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager


class UserProfile(User):            
    phone = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, 
        blank=False,
    )
    skype = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, 
        blank=False,
    )   

    @classmethod
    def get_new_authors_entries(self):
        return self.objects.filter(is_active=1, is_superuser=0).order_by('-date_joined')    

    @classmethod
    def get_count_authors_entries(self):
        return self.objects.filter(is_active=1, is_superuser=0).order_by('-date_joined').count()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, don't call the argument to a classmethod `self`. By convention, that's used for instances: the argument to a classmethod is `cls`.

Secondly, the only difference between the methods is the addition of `count()`. So why can't you just put that on the result of the call to the other one?

```
@classmethod
def get_count_authors_entries(cls):
    return cls.get_new_authors_entries().count()
```

Also note that it is more idiomatic in Django to put these methods on a custom manager, rather than using classmethods. And finally, I would question why you need the count method at all, since you can add count() onto the result of the get_new_authors_entries method wherever you call it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to define two methods when you can get away with one.

```
@classmethod
def get_authors_entries(cls):
    return self.objects.filter(is_active=1, is_superuser=0).order_by('-date_joined')
```

Now if you want to get new author entries just call `get_authors_entries` and if you want to get the count just call `count` method on the queryset returned.